# environment variables does not work when running multiple containers in one pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

When running mysql in one pod, env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD works as expected.

However, if running mysql with other containers in one pod, it seemed that "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" did not work as expected.

Although variable was set into mysql container, actually password is empty when connecting to mysql within container.

The detailed deployment is as below,

```
   spec:
      containers:
      - name: ocai
        image: aura/web:develop
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      - name: notebook
        image: aura/all-spark-notebook:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8889
        command: ["sh", "-c", "jupyter-notebook --port=8889 --NotebookApp.token='secret' --config=/jupyter_notebook_config.py --no-browser"]
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/ai_lab/ocai/
              name: nb-data
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 4Gi
      - name: mysql
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: Ocai@1234
        image: aura/mysql:5.7
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
              name: mysql-data
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 2G
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ocai-mysql-claim
        - name: nb-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ocai-nb-claim
```

Comment: Please check the Yaml file, you might have accidentally exposed your secret App token to the internet. If this is indeed your App token, you should change it.

Comment: I found the problem. Because I didn't create the persistent volume properly,  env didn't work as expected. However, I didn't know why. But after fixing persistent problem, I could make that works.

Comment: May i know what is that persistent problem? are you able to access env var inside your application at runtime (ex : os.environ.get("env_name"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by persistent storage.

I didn't create pv/pvc correctly, so pod did not work as expected although it's started.

I also found that fi mounting hostPath as persistent storage, the pod failed to start.

Then I recreated PV/PVC, it worked well.

Answer (score 3):

In your deployment config yaml, the `env` value is *only* set for the mysql container. Therefore, even though they share the same pod, the environment variable will only be available to the mysql container.